# Change "onclick" call dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have javascript call for an image during `onclick` event.

```
onclick="removeFeetype(5);"
```

I need to change that to `onclick="removeFeetype(4);` during some other call using the attribute `ID` by jQuery. 
Which means I need to change the function call from 5 to 4.

Please I need your help. Thanks in advance.

I tried using the following code to change the "onclick" call method. But it is not changed on my html code for that particular element with the ID "removeButton".

------------------------FIRST-------------------------------

```
var changeval = 4;
var onclickval = "removeFeetype("+changeval+");";
$('#removeButton').attr("onclick", onclickval);
```

---

------------------------SECOND-----------------------------------------

```
var changeval = 4;
var next = "removeFeetype(" + changeval + ");";
var newclick_next = eval("(function(){"+next+"});");
$('#removeButton').attr('onclick','').unbind().click(newclick_next);
```

---

Actually my task is,

i have sequence for the rows with the ID

```
id="removeButton1" onclick="removeFeetype(1);"
id="removeButton2" onclick="removeFeetype(2);"
id="removeButton3" onclick="removeFeetype(3);"
id="removeButton4" onclick="removeFeetype(4);"
```

.....

If i delete the removeButton2 using the function removeFeetype(2).

then i need the change remaining to

```
ID = removeButton3 to removeButton2 and so on and
ONCLICK = removeFeetype(3) to removeFeetype(2) and so on
```

I can change the ID removeButton3 to removeButton2 and so on.

But i can't change the onclick method call from "removeFeetype(3);" to "removeFeetype(2);"

Hope now it is clear. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Why don't you keep the function same but change the input parameters depending on the situation ?

Comment: You're probably better off (re)binding to it using the `$('link_element_id').click(function(){ //code here })`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) attributes to pass value to javascript, you will need to pass the source object using `this`.

```
<input type="text" data-someAtt="1" onclick="removeFeetype(this)" />

function removeFeetype(obj)
{
    $(obj).data("someAtt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the onclick attribute value like this:

```
$("#link").attr("onclick", "removeFeetype(4);");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/neX7W/

Answer (score 1):

Lets use jQuery overall

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Fee").click(function(){
       removeFeetype($(this).attr('data-value'));
       $(this).attr('data-value',$(this).attr('data-value') - 1);
    }); 
});
```

I'll expect your link to be

```
<div class="Fee" data-value="5">Link</div>
```

Comment: Using the `id` attribute to store the value is probably a really bad idea, since they have to be unique.

Comment: It is an example, i know you can do it in better ways, see the note. I'll keep its easy so he understands then he can do what he likes.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with the assessment that this is just "worse", I think I'd go as far as to say that it's just plain wrong. If you know that it can be done using a `data-*` attribute, an example of how that would be achieved would be considerably better (I'd even upvote that).